# Implementing a .a file (static library into RoboVM)?

Tags: java, ios, google-analytics, robovm

I'm trying to implement the Google Analytics RoboVM binding into my project.

I tried using the LibGDX download from http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/robovm-ios-bindings/ but this failed because of this issue:

https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/issues/48

So I downloaded an updated version of robovm binding using git from the robovm-bindings (https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings) copy and pasted the src into my ios project.

Now I've looked everything but I cannot find a solution as too where to put the libgoogleanalytics.a (which I had to copy from the LibGDX jar as I've not idea where to get this?)

Can someone help me out here, spent days trying to get Analytics working in RoboVM....

Answer (score 0):

> Now I've looked everything but I cannot find a solution as too where
>   to put the libgoogleanalytics.a

Usually static libraries take their place under ios project in libs/ios/ folder. You have to create this folder if it does not exist by default. So put your libgoogleanalytics.a to libs/ios and make appropriate changes in robovm.xml:

```
<libs>
    .. other libs that you are using
   <lib> libs/ios/libgoogleanalytics.a </lib> 
    ..
</libs>
```

In the latest release robovm + libGDX  probably  you will not find *libs tag* in robovm.xml, if so then you have to add it by yourself.